# How do I make each link show its own text on the background when hovering?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have 3 links when hovering over which I want a certain text to appear in the background. That is, when I hover the mouse cursor over "Works", "Works" appears in the background, when I hover over "About", "About" appears in the background. I don't understand how to do this if I add a second text, they climb on top of each other.

I attach my code below (You need to open the whole page to see the result).

I will be grateful if you help

```css
.info {
  max-width: 1920px;
  padding: 40px 0 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.info__container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  align-items: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  list-style-type: none;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #1c1c1c;
  background-color: #ebebeb;
  margin: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
  height: 150px;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

 .info__text{
  width: 60px; 
  z-index: 1;
} 

.info__black-hover {
  background: #1c1c1c;
  width: 1920px;
  height: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  transition: 0.5s opacity, 0.5s visibility, 0.6s height ease-in;
}

.info__text:hover~.info__black-hover{
  width: 100%;
  height: 150px;
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
  background: #1c1c1c;
} 

.info__text_hidden {
  font-size: 210px;
  font-family: "Roobert";
  letter-spacing: -10px;
  position: absolute;
  color: #474747; 
  bottom: -38px;
  left: 870px;
  z-index: 1;
  transform: translateY(70%);
  transition: all 1.3s ease;
}

 .info__text:hover~.info__text_hidden {
    visibility: visible;
    color: #636262;
    transform: translateY(0%);
}  


.info__text_decoration {
  font-family: "RoxboughCF-Regular";
  position: absolute;
  left: -185px;
  bottom: 2px;
}

.info__number {
  font-size: 22px;
  color: #7a7a7a;
}

.info__link {
  text-decoration: none;
  list-style-type: none;
  color: #1c1c1c; 
}

.info__link:hover {
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<section class="info">
      <ul class="info__container">
        <li  class="info__text"><span class="info__number">01</span><a class="info__link" href="#"> Works</a></li>
        <div class="info__text_hidden"><span class="info__text_decoration">W</span>orks</div> 
        <li class="info__text"><span class="info__number">02</span><a class="info__link"  href="#"> About</a></li>
        <div class="info__text_hidden"><span class="info__text_decoration">A</span>bout</div> 
        <li class="info__text"><span class="info__number">03</span><a class="info__link"  href="#"> Contact</a></li>
        <div class="info__black-hover"></div>
      </ul>
    </section>
```

Comment: You may like to put your code through a validator as currently the HTML is not legal (div cannot be a direct child of ul).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could perhaps use pseudo `::before` elements with `attr()` function as the  css content value...

`content: attr(data-text);`

Data attribute then set in the `.info__link` anchor tag...

`<a class="info__link" href="#" data-text="Works">Works</a>`

Could do with some refining but the method uses less markup.

See working demo below and fiddle... https://jsfiddle.net/joshmoto/714rpkw8/1/

```css
.info {
  max-width: 1920px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.info__container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  align-items: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  list-style-type: none;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #1c1c1c;
  background-color: #ebebeb;
  margin: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
  height: 150px;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.info__text {
  width: 60px;
}

.info__number {
  font-size: 22px;
  color: #7a7a7a;
}

.info__link {
  text-decoration: none;
  list-style-type: none;
  color: #1c1c1c;
}

.info__link:hover {
  color: white;
}

.info__link::before {
  content: attr(data-text);
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  top: 50%;
  bottom: 50%;
  transition: all .5s ease;
  font-size: 100px;
  line-height: auto;
  font-family: "Roobert";
  color: #474747;
  background: #1c1c1c;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: -10;
}

.info__link:hover::before {
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<section class="info">
  <ul class="info__container">
    <li class="info__text">
      <span class="info__number">01</span> 
      <a class="info__link" href="#" data-text="Works">Works</a>
    </li>  
    <li class="info__text">
      <span class="info__number">02</span> 
      <a class="info__link" href="#" data-text="About">About</a>
    </li>
    <li class="info__text">
      <span class="info__number">03</span> 
      <a class="info__link" href="#" data-text="Contact">Contact</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</section>
```

---

Another option, is you can use `:has()`, tho not fully supported by all browsers yet.

See `:has()` compatibility https://caniuse.com/?search=has

Using `:has()` in this example below runs the background transition effect behind all the before elems using `attr()` to render the `data-text` attribute value.

See working demo below and fiddle... https://jsfiddle.net/joshmoto/y9164hxz/

```css
.info {
  max-width: 1920px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.info__container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  align-items: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  list-style-type: none;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #1c1c1c;
  background: #ebebeb;
  margin: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
  height: 150px;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.info__container:has(.info__link:hover) .info__link:not(:hover) {
  color: #7a7a7a;
}

.info__text {
  width: 60px;
}

.info__text::before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 50%;
  bottom: 50%;
  transition: all .5s ease;
  background: #1c1c1c;
  z-index: -11;
}

.info__text:has(.info__link:hover)::before {
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

.info__number {
  font-size: 22px;
  color: #7a7a7a;
  display: inline-block;
}

.info__link {
  text-decoration: none;
  list-style-type: none;
  color: #1c1c1c;
}

.info__link:hover {
  color: white;
}

.info__link::before {
  content: attr(data-text);
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 50%;
  bottom: 50%;
  font-size: 100px;
  line-height: auto;
  font-family: "Roobert";
  color: #474747;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: -10;
  pointer-events: none;
  transition: all .5s ease;
}

.info__link:hover::before {
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<section class="info">
  <ul class="info__container">
    <li class="info__text">
      <span class="info__number">01</span> 
      <a class="info__link" href="#" data-text="Works">Works</a>
    </li>  
    <li class="info__text">
      <span class="info__number">02</span> 
      <a class="info__link" href="#" data-text="About">About</a>
    </li>
    <li class="info__text">
      <span class="info__number">03</span> 
      <a class="info__link" href="#" data-text="Contact">Contact</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</section>
```

Let me know if this works or you need more refinement.

---

**Update**

I like your site design, but those effects you got on your text would be tricky to do using my pseudo element pure css version.

The closest I could get to your current design using pure CSS and pseudo elements was like this...

See fiddle version here... https://jsfiddle.net/joshmoto/d8rf93mp/

```css
.info {
  max-width: 1920px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.info__container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  align-items: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  list-style-type: none;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #1c1c1c;
  background: #ebebeb;
  margin: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
  height: 150px;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.info__container:has(.info__link:hover) .info__link:not(:hover) {
  color: #7a7a7a;
}

.info__text {
  width: 70px;
}

.info__text::before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 100%;
  bottom: 0%;
  transition: all .5s ease;
  background: #1c1c1c;
  z-index: -11;
}

.info__text:has(.info__link:hover)::before {
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

.info__number {
  font-size: 22px;
  color: #7a7a7a;
  display: inline-block;
}

.info__link {
  text-decoration: none;
  list-style-type: none;
  color: #1c1c1c;
}

.info__link:hover {
  color: white;
}

.info__link::before {
  content: attr(data-text);
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 50%;
  bottom: 50%;
  font-size: 100px;
  vertical-align: baseline;
  line-height: 150px;
  font-family: "Roobert";
  color: #474747;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: -10;
  pointer-events: none;
  transition: all .5s ease;
  text-align: center;
  transform: skewY(45deg);
  transform-origin: 0% 0%;
}

.info__link:hover::before {
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  transform: skewY(0deg);
}

.info__link>SPAN {
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.info__link>SPAN::before {
  content: attr(data-text);
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  transform: translateY(0%);
  transition: all .5s ease;
  transform-origin: 100% 100%;
}

.info__link:hover>SPAN::before {
  transform: translateY(-100%) skewY(45deg);
}

.info__link>SPAN::after {
  content: attr(data-text);
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  top: 100%;
  transition: all .5s ease;
  transform: skewY(45deg);
  transform-origin: 0 0;
}

.info__link:hover>SPAN::after {
  top: 0;
  transform: skewY(0);
}
```

```html
<section class="info">
  <ul class="info__container">
    <li class="info__text">
      <span class="info__number">01</span>
      <a class="info__link" href="#" data-text="Works">
        <span data-text="Works"></span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="info__text">
      <span class="info__number">02</span>
      <a class="info__link" href="#" data-text="About">
        <span data-text="About"></span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="info__text">
      <span class="info__number">03</span>
      <a class="info__link" href="#" data-text="Contact">
        <span data-text="Contact"></span>
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</section>
```

Comment: Hello, I really liked your version, is it possible to make the text on the background appear in the middle (and not on the left) or do I need to use JS for this? Example [link](https://huyml.co/home.html)

Comment: Wow, thank you for your help, thanks to you I have become even better at css. I will take your version to my website. Unfortunately, I can't like it, because the reputation is too low.

Answer (score 0):

- You can use `data-attribute` and access it in `::before` or `::afetr` css's `content` property. for more info visit [this](https://css-tricks.com/css-attr-function-got-nothin-custom-properties/).
- Below we are accessing `data-linkfor` value and displaying it in background.

```
/*Added css for getting currently hoverd text in backgrouond*/
.info__text::before {
  content: attr(data-linkfor);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  font-size: 56px;
  opacity: 0;
  color: #fff;
  transition: .5s;
}

.info__text:hover::before {
  opacity: 0.6;
}
```

```css
.info {
  max-width: 1920px;
  padding: 40px 0 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.info__container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  align-items: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  list-style-type: none;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #1c1c1c;
  background-color: #ebebeb;
  margin: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
  height: 150px;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.info__text {
  width: 60px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.info__black-hover {
  background: #1c1c1c;
  width: 1920px;
  height: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  transition: 0.5s opacity, 0.5s visibility, 0.6s height ease-in;
}

.info__text:hover~.info__black-hover {
  width: 100%;
  height: 150px;
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
  background: #1c1c1c;
}

.info__text_hidden {
  font-size: 210px;
  font-family: "Roobert";
  letter-spacing: -10px;
  position: absolute;
  color: #474747;
  bottom: -38px;
  left: 870px;
  z-index: 1;
  transform: translateY(70%);
  transition: all 1.3s ease;
}

.info__text:hover~.info__text_hidden {
  visibility: visible;
  color: #636262;
  transform: translateY(0%);
}

.info__text_decoration {
  font-family: "RoxboughCF-Regular";
  position: absolute;
  left: -185px;
  bottom: 2px;
}

.info__number {
  font-size: 22px;
  color: #7a7a7a;
}

.info__link {
  text-decoration: none;
  list-style-type: none;
  color: #1c1c1c;
}

.info__text:hover .info__link {
  color: #fff;
}

.info__link:hover {
  color: white;
}


/*Added css for getting currently hoverd text in backgrouond*/

.info__text::before {
  content: attr(data-linkfor);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  font-size: 56px;
  opacity: 0;
  color: #fff;
  transition: .5s;
}

.info__text:hover::before {
  opacity: 0.6;
}
```

```html
<section class="info">
  <ul class="info__container">
    <li data-linkfor="Works" class="info__text"><span class="info__number">01</span><a class="info__link" href="#"> Works</a></li>
    <li data-linkfor="About" class="info__text"><span class="info__number">02</span><a class="info__link" href="#"> About</a></li>
    <li data-linkfor="Contact" class="info__text"><span class="info__number">03</span><a class="info__link" href="#"> Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</section>
```

Comment: This is not legal HTML (ul elements cannot have div elements as direct children). It also gives a strange result if you hover up near the top left - Contact is shown.

Comment: @AHaworth, I didn't notice questiner's html structure. Sorry about that I have changed it

Answer (score 0):

Try this, I think it will be much better and simple:

**CSS**

```
section {
    display: flex;
    position: relative;
    justify-content: space-between;
    transition: .3s;
    font-family:sans-serif;
    background: #eee;
}
section:hover {
    background: black;
}
section:hover a{
    color: white;
}
section a {
    width: 33%;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 30px;
    color: black;
    height: 400px;
    display: flex;
    padding-top: 100px;
    justify-content: center;
}
section .background_text {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    color: white;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    font-size: 100px;
    pointer-events: none;
    transform: translateY(100px);
    opacity: 0;
    transition: .3s;
}
section .background_text.active {
    transform: translateY(0);
    opacity: 1;
}
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
let background_text = document.querySelector('.background_text');
let links = document.querySelectorAll('a.link');
links.forEach( e => {
    e.onmouseover = function () {
        background_text.classList.add('active');
        background_text.textContent = e.textContent;
    } 
    e.onmouseleave = function () {
        background_text.classList.remove('active');
    }
});
```

**HTML**

```
<section>
    <div class="background_text"></div>
    <a href="#" class="link">Works</a>
    <a href="#" class="link">About</a>
    <a href="#" class="link">Contact</a>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Making yur HTML into 'legal' code, by putting the divs holding the larger text into the li elements instead of separately, we then alter the hover state CSS so that it is the child of the hovered element that is being transformed (not a sibling as in the original).

This snippet has just those changes:

```css
.info {
  max-width: 1920px;
  padding: 40px 0 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.info__container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  align-items: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  list-style-type: none;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #1c1c1c;
  background-color: #ebebeb;
  margin: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
  height: 150px;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.info__text {
  width: 60px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.info__black-hover {
  background: #1c1c1c;
  width: 1920px;
  height: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  transition: 0.5s opacity, 0.5s visibility, 0.6s height ease-in;
}

.info__text:hover .info__black-hover {
  width: 100%;
  height: 150px;
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
  background: #1c1c1c;
}

.info__text_hidden {
  font-size: 210px;
  font-family: "Roobert";
  letter-spacing: -10px;
  position: absolute;
  color: #474747;
  bottom: -38px;
  left: 870px;
  z-index: 1;
  transform: translateY(70%);
  transition: all 1.3s ease;
}

.info__text:hover .info__text_hidden {
  visibility: visible;
  color: #636262;
  transform: translateY(0%);
}

.info__text_decoration {
  font-family: "RoxboughCF-Regular";
  position: absolute;
  left: -185px;
  bottom: 2px;
}

.info__number {
  font-size: 22px;
  color: #7a7a7a;
}

.info__link {
  text-decoration: none;
  list-style-type: none;
  color: #1c1c1c;
}

.info__link:hover {
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<section class="info">
  <ul class="info__container">
    <li class="info__text"><span class="info__number">01</span><a class="info__link" href="#"> Works</a>
      <div class="info__text_hidden"><span class="info__text_decoration">W</span>orks</div>
    </li>
    <li class="info__text"><span class="info__number">02</span><a class="info__link" href="#"> About</a>
      <div class="info__text_hidden"><span class="info__text_decoration">A</span>bout</div>
    </li>
    <li class="info__text"><span class="info__number">03</span><a class="info__link" href="#"> Contact</a>
      <div class="info__black-hover"></div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</section>
```

There are other things you may want to look at. For example, would the user of first-character be helpful instead of a separate span element in the text of the large words. Also, what exactly you want the effect on the Contact element when hovered to be. At the moment just a black rectangle appears.

Comment: Hello, I would like that when hovering over "Contact", there was also an inscription "Contact", and a black square filled the entire background when hovering over a certain link. Example [link](https://huyml.co/home.html). Thank you for your code, I really liked how you did.